# How to configure cortana in window lumia 630?

Tags: window

I use Window lumia 630

How to configure cortana in window lumia 630?

i am trying trying lots of time but not start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution this will also working

Cortana's settings

One advantage of a digital personal assistant is that she won't take it personally if you want to adjust her settings and how she works. You can get to Cortana's settings on your Windows Phone in two ways:

Press the Search Search icon button to go to Cortana, then tap Cortana's NotebookCortana's Notebook icon > Settings.
In the App list, tap Settings Settings Tile, swipe over to Applications, then tap Cortana.
Here's what you can do in Cortana's settings.

for more... see this link

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/cortana/cortanas-settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to put ur location as US in settings
speech too in english